# Функция SlideUp при фиксированном меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Эффект: текст выезжает снизу и не заезжает за меню, а останавливается на расстоянии, равном высоте меню + десятка пикселей, чтобы отступ был от меню и не прилипал к нему. Получается не очень сейчас... Решение нужно на jquery или javascript.

```js
    $('#text').css('margin-top','700px');

        $('#text').slideUp(2000, function() {
            $(this).css("display", "block");
            $(this).css("margin-top", "50px");
        });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;

}
.menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list0style0type: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
#text {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Главная</li>
    <li>Продукция</li>
    <li>Контакты</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="text">РЕКОМЕНДАЦИИ

Для поддержания красоты и долговечности мебели рекомендуется соблюдать следующие правила:
Использовать мебель в соответствии с ее функциональным назначением.
Температура воздуха в помещениях должна быть не ниже +2 С и не выше +40 С, относительная влажность –60-70%. Существенное отклонение от указанного режима приводит к значительному ухудшению потребительских качеств мебели.
Не рекомендуется располагать мебель ближе 0,5-0,7 м от отопительных приборов и других источников тепла, а также избегать воздействия прямых солнечных лучей, которое вызывает старение лакокрасочного покрытия, изменение его цвета и приводит к деформации мебельных щитов.
Сборку мебели необходимо производить в полном соответствии со сборочными чертежами (схемами). Для сборки сложных изделий рекомендуется привлекать квалифицированных специалистов.
При эксплуатации мебели не следует прилагать чрезмерных усилий для открывания дверей, использования выдвижных ящиков и иных подвижных частей.
Следует оберегать поверхность мебели и ее конструктивные элементы от механических повреждений.
Для ухода за мебелью применяют специальные чистящие и полирующие средства.
Общие условия по эксплуатации (хранению) и уходу за мебелью Срок, в течение которого мебель сохраняет красоту и исправность, значительно зависит от условий ее эксплуатации. Придерживаясь некоторых простых практических советов, вы сможете поддержать всегда в наилучшем состоянии все элементы вашей мебели.
Климатические характеристики и условия окружающей среды

Очень важно понять, насколько климатические характеристики и условия окружающей среды могут повлиять на внешний вид и качественные характеристики мебели. Так как мебельные изделия чувствительны к свету, влажности, сухости, теплу и холоду, рекомендуется избегать продолжительности воздействия одного или нескольких этих условий, так как это вызывает ускоренное старение лакокрасочного покрытия (изменение цвета, растрескивание, шелушение и т.п.), коробление и деформацию деревянных элементов мебели, старение материала обивки и т.д.
Свет

Не допускайте прямого воздействия солнечных лучей на мебельные изделия. Продолжительное прямое воздействие света на некоторые участки может вызвать понижение их хроматических характеристик по сравнению с другими участками, которые меньше подвергались излучению. В случае замены и/или добавления новых компонентов в интерьер из одних и тех же коллекций в разные моменты времени, а также из разных партий, может возникнуть цветовое различие элементов, составляющих мебель. Данное различие не может считаться признаком низкого качества мебели. Как правило, оно становится менее заметным с течением времени и является совершенно естественным.
Температура

Высокое значение тепла или холода, а также внезапные перепады температуры, могут серьезно повредить мебельное изделие или его части. Мебельные изделия не должны быть расположены менее 1м от источников тепла. Рекомендуемая температура воздуха при хранении и(или) эксплуатации + 10°С — +25°С. Не допускайте попадания на мебельные изделия горячих предметов (утюги, посуда с кипятком и т.п.) или продолжительного воздействия вызывающих нагревание излучений (свет мощных ламп, неэкранированные микроволновые излучатели и т.п.).
Влажность

Рекомендуемая относительная влажность местонахождения мебельного изделия 60%-70%. Не следует поддерживать в течение продолжительного времени условия крайней влажности или сухости в помещении, а тем более — их периодической смены. С течением времени такие условия могут повлиять на целостность мебельных изделий или их элементов. Тем не менее, если вы создали такие условия, то рекомендуется часто проветривать помещения и, по мере возможности, пользоваться осушителями или увлажнителями воздуха для нормализации влажности. Всегда содержите поверхности мебели в полной сухости. Поверхности деталей мебели следует протирать сухой мягкой тканью (фланель, сукно, плюш, миткаль). Уход за рабочими поверхностями (столешницы, мойки и т.п.), как правило, должен осуществляться мягкой влажной тканью, поролоновой губкой или специальными щетками, возможно с применением соответствующих моющих средств. Рекомендуется очистить любую часть мебели как можно скорее после того, как она испачкалась. Если вы оставляете загрязнение на некоторое время, то заметно повышается опасность образования разводов, пятен и повреждений мебельных изделий и их частей. В случае стойких загрязнений рекомендуется использовать специальные очистители, которые в настоящее время представлены в достаточно широком ассортименте и, помимо надлежащих очищающих качеств, обладают полирующими, защитными, консервирующими, ароматизирующими и иными полезными свойствами. В этом случае необходимо следовать инструкциям производителей очистителей о порядке и области (для каких поверхностей и материалов предназначены) их применения. При отсутствии специальных средств допускается также уход (чистка) с применением небольшого количества водного раствора нейтрального моющего средства (например, хозяйственное мыло, 2%-моюшее средство, 98%-вода и т.п.). По завершении любой чистки необходимо высушить (насухо протереть) все части, которые подвергались влажной чистке. Рекомендуется обратить особое внимание на внутренние и мало вентилируемые части, на оконечности и на точки соединения. Помните, что нельзя использовать для чистки ткани, губки или перчатки, пропитанные продуктами, которые не должны вступать в контакт с очищаемыми материалами.
Агрессивные среды и абразивные материалы

Ни в коем случае не допускайте воздействия на мебельные изделия агрессивных жидкостей (кислот, щелочей, масел, растворителей и т.п.), содержащих такие жидкости продуктов или их паров. Подобные вещества и соединения являются химически активными — реакция с ними повлечет негативные последствия для вашей мебели или даже здоровья. Также стоит помнить, что некоторые специфические моющие (чистящие) составы могут содержать высокую концентрацию агрессивных химических веществ и (или) абразивные составы. Применение подобных моющих средств недопустимо!
Проветривание

Рекомендуется не заслонять решетки и воздухозаборные отверстия, необходимые для вентиляции электробытовых приборов.
Особенности эксплуатации и ухода за корпусной мебелью

Корпусная мебель (шкафы, кровати, комоды, туалетные столы, стеллажи, прихожие, кухни, столы, тумбы и т.д.) должна использоваться в соответствии с функциональным назначением каждого отдельного предмета.
Особенности эксплуатации корпусной мебели

Все тяжести следует размещать внутри шкафов, комодов, туалетных столов, тумбочек, стеллажей и т.п., таким образом, чтобы добиться равномерного распределения нагрузки по всей имеющейся площади и обеспечить необходимое равновесие скользящих частей. Вещи на полках рекомендуется размещать по принципу: наиболее тяжелые — ближе к краям (опорам), более легкие — ближе к центру. Высокие элементы (колонны, многоярусные шкафы и т.д.) рекомендуется больше нагружать в нижних секциях для обеспечения лучшей устойчивости этих элементов. При эксплуатации корпусной мебели не допускается статическая вертикальная нагрузка (в особенности с приложением усилия к одной точке): на дно ящиков — более 5 даН*, на полки (шкафов, стеллажей) более -10 даН*. Нормальное усилие открытия дверей — до 3 даН*; усилие выдвижения ящиков — до 5 даН*. Примечание: *нагрузке (усилию) в 1 даН приблизительно соответствует воздействие веса в 1кг! Не проводите по поверхностям мебели и не ударяйте их острыми (режущими) или тяжелыми твердыми предметами. Обращаем Ваше внимание на то, что элементы кухонных гарнитуров, расположенные вблизи газовой или электрической плиты, подвержены повышенной тепловой нагрузке, в силу чего рекомендуется отделять их от источников тепла соответствующими теплоизоляционными материалами. Просим вас принять к сведению, что в мебельные изделия может устанавливаться исключительно специальная «встраиваемая» бытовая техника. Такая техника выполняется производителями в соответствии со специфическими нормативами и техническими условиями (в части электробезопасности, влагоотвода, теплообмена, вентиляции и т.п.) и, как правило, стоит несколько дороже «не встраиваемых» аналогов. Помните: ни в коем случае не следует использовать обычную бытовую технику в качестве встраиваемой, это может представлять реальную опасность для жизни или здоровья людей и/или сохранности имущества!</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементу задаётся margin-top: 750px; а всё остальное при помощи javascript.

```js
setTimeout (function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  text.style.marginTop = '50px';
  text.style.transition = 'all linear 2s';
},0);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;

}
.menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list0style0type: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
#text {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 750px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Главная</li>
    <li>Продукция</li>
    <li>Контакты</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="text">РЕКОМЕНДАЦИИ

Для поддержания красоты и долговечности мебели рекомендуется соблюдать следующие правила:
Использовать мебель в соответствии с ее функциональным назначением.
Температура воздуха в помещениях должна быть не ниже +2 С и не выше +40 С, относительная влажность –60-70%. Существенное отклонение от указанного режима приводит к значительному ухудшению потребительских качеств мебели.
Не рекомендуется располагать мебель ближе 0,5-0,7 м от отопительных приборов и других источников тепла, а также избегать воздействия прямых солнечных лучей, которое вызывает старение лакокрасочного покрытия, изменение его цвета и приводит к деформации мебельных щитов.
Сборку мебели необходимо производить в полном соответствии со сборочными чертежами (схемами). Для сборки сложных изделий рекомендуется привлекать квалифицированных специалистов.
При эксплуатации мебели не следует прилагать чрезмерных усилий для открывания дверей, использования выдвижных ящиков и иных подвижных частей.
Следует оберегать поверхность мебели и ее конструктивные элементы от механических повреждений.
Для ухода за мебелью применяют специальные чистящие и полирующие средства.
Общие условия по эксплуатации (хранению) и уходу за мебелью Срок, в течение которого мебель сохраняет красоту и исправность, значительно зависит от условий ее эксплуатации. Придерживаясь некоторых простых практических советов, вы сможете поддержать всегда в наилучшем состоянии все элементы вашей мебели.
Климатические характеристики и условия окружающей среды

Очень важно понять, насколько климатические характеристики и условия окружающей среды могут повлиять на внешний вид и качественные характеристики мебели. Так как мебельные изделия чувствительны к свету, влажности, сухости, теплу и холоду, рекомендуется избегать продолжительности воздействия одного или нескольких этих условий, так как это вызывает ускоренное старение лакокрасочного покрытия (изменение цвета, растрескивание, шелушение и т.п.), коробление и деформацию деревянных элементов мебели, старение материала обивки и т.д.
Свет

Не допускайте прямого воздействия солнечных лучей на мебельные изделия. Продолжительное прямое воздействие света на некоторые участки может вызвать понижение их хроматических характеристик по сравнению с другими участками, которые меньше подвергались излучению. В случае замены и/или добавления новых компонентов в интерьер из одних и тех же коллекций в разные моменты времени, а также из разных партий, может возникнуть цветовое различие элементов, составляющих мебель. Данное различие не может считаться признаком низкого качества мебели. Как правило, оно становится менее заметным с течением времени и является совершенно естественным.
Температура

Высокое значение тепла или холода, а также внезапные перепады температуры, могут серьезно повредить мебельное изделие или его части. Мебельные изделия не должны быть расположены менее 1м от источников тепла. Рекомендуемая температура воздуха при хранении и(или) эксплуатации + 10°С — +25°С. Не допускайте попадания на мебельные изделия горячих предметов (утюги, посуда с кипятком и т.п.) или продолжительного воздействия вызывающих нагревание излучений (свет мощных ламп, неэкранированные микроволновые излучатели и т.п.).
Влажность

Рекомендуемая относительная влажность местонахождения мебельного изделия 60%-70%. Не следует поддерживать в течение продолжительного времени условия крайней влажности или сухости в помещении, а тем более — их периодической смены. С течением времени такие условия могут повлиять на целостность мебельных изделий или их элементов. Тем не менее, если вы создали такие условия, то рекомендуется часто проветривать помещения и, по мере возможности, пользоваться осушителями или увлажнителями воздуха для нормализации влажности. Всегда содержите поверхности мебели в полной сухости. Поверхности деталей мебели следует протирать сухой мягкой тканью (фланель, сукно, плюш, миткаль). Уход за рабочими поверхностями (столешницы, мойки и т.п.), как правило, должен осуществляться мягкой влажной тканью, поролоновой губкой или специальными щетками, возможно с применением соответствующих моющих средств. Рекомендуется очистить любую часть мебели как можно скорее после того, как она испачкалась. Если вы оставляете загрязнение на некоторое время, то заметно повышается опасность образования разводов, пятен и повреждений мебельных изделий и их частей. В случае стойких загрязнений рекомендуется использовать специальные очистители, которые в настоящее время представлены в достаточно широком ассортименте и, помимо надлежащих очищающих качеств, обладают полирующими, защитными, консервирующими, ароматизирующими и иными полезными свойствами. В этом случае необходимо следовать инструкциям производителей очистителей о порядке и области (для каких поверхностей и материалов предназначены) их применения. При отсутствии специальных средств допускается также уход (чистка) с применением небольшого количества водного раствора нейтрального моющего средства (например, хозяйственное мыло, 2%-моюшее средство, 98%-вода и т.п.). По завершении любой чистки необходимо высушить (насухо протереть) все части, которые подвергались влажной чистке. Рекомендуется обратить особое внимание на внутренние и мало вентилируемые части, на оконечности и на точки соединения. Помните, что нельзя использовать для чистки ткани, губки или перчатки, пропитанные продуктами, которые не должны вступать в контакт с очищаемыми материалами.
Агрессивные среды и абразивные материалы

Ни в коем случае не допускайте воздействия на мебельные изделия агрессивных жидкостей (кислот, щелочей, масел, растворителей и т.п.), содержащих такие жидкости продуктов или их паров. Подобные вещества и соединения являются химически активными — реакция с ними повлечет негативные последствия для вашей мебели или даже здоровья. Также стоит помнить, что некоторые специфические моющие (чистящие) составы могут содержать высокую концентрацию агрессивных химических веществ и (или) абразивные составы. Применение подобных моющих средств недопустимо!
Проветривание

Рекомендуется не заслонять решетки и воздухозаборные отверстия, необходимые для вентиляции электробытовых приборов.
Особенности эксплуатации и ухода за корпусной мебелью

Корпусная мебель (шкафы, кровати, комоды, туалетные столы, стеллажи, прихожие, кухни, столы, тумбы и т.д.) должна использоваться в соответствии с функциональным назначением каждого отдельного предмета.
Особенности эксплуатации корпусной мебели

Все тяжести следует размещать внутри шкафов, комодов, туалетных столов, тумбочек, стеллажей и т.п., таким образом, чтобы добиться равномерного распределения нагрузки по всей имеющейся площади и обеспечить необходимое равновесие скользящих частей. Вещи на полках рекомендуется размещать по принципу: наиболее тяжелые — ближе к краям (опорам), более легкие — ближе к центру. Высокие элементы (колонны, многоярусные шкафы и т.д.) рекомендуется больше нагружать в нижних секциях для обеспечения лучшей устойчивости этих элементов. При эксплуатации корпусной мебели не допускается статическая вертикальная нагрузка (в особенности с приложением усилия к одной точке): на дно ящиков — более 5 даН*, на полки (шкафов, стеллажей) более -10 даН*. Нормальное усилие открытия дверей — до 3 даН*; усилие выдвижения ящиков — до 5 даН*. Примечание: *нагрузке (усилию) в 1 даН приблизительно соответствует воздействие веса в 1кг! Не проводите по поверхностям мебели и не ударяйте их острыми (режущими) или тяжелыми твердыми предметами. Обращаем Ваше внимание на то, что элементы кухонных гарнитуров, расположенные вблизи газовой или электрической плиты, подвержены повышенной тепловой нагрузке, в силу чего рекомендуется отделять их от источников тепла соответствующими теплоизоляционными материалами. Просим вас принять к сведению, что в мебельные изделия может устанавливаться исключительно специальная «встраиваемая» бытовая техника. Такая техника выполняется производителями в соответствии со специфическими нормативами и техническими условиями (в части электробезопасности, влагоотвода, теплообмена, вентиляции и т.п.) и, как правило, стоит несколько дороже «не встраиваемых» аналогов. Помните: ни в коем случае не следует использовать обычную бытовую технику в качестве встраиваемой, это может представлять реальную опасность для жизни или здоровья людей и/или сохранности имущества!</div>
```